# Split a number with regex on the decimal point or end of string.

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is an example of what I want to happen

50.1->['50','.1']
50  ->['50','']

I have tried using `.split` or `.match`.  I got it to work with decimals, but not without.

```
'51.11'.split(/(?=\.)/);//works
'51'.split(/(?=\.)|$/);//doesn't
```

I'm aware I could do this in several steps, but I thought it might be possible with regex. I am trying to learn regex, but the pipe character does not behave as I expect it to.  Also, I am not sure if this is even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.match` with `/(\d+)((?:\.\d+)?)/`.

`/(\d+)(\.\d+|)/` would also work. The second group will match either a dot and 1 or more digits, or an empty string.

Answer (score 4):

You could just use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with `/(\d+)(\.\d+)?/`:

```
m = "50".match(/(\d+)(\.\d+)?/)
# ["50", "50", undefined]

m = "50.4".match(/(\d+)(\.\d+)?/)
# ["50.4", "50", ".4"]
```

The `m[1]` and `m[2]` values are populated with the capture groups.

If you really need a space, you could try something like `/(\d+)((?:\.?)\d*)?/`:

```
m = "50.0".match(/(\d+)((?:\.?)\d*)?/)
# ["50.0", "50", ".0"]

m = "50.".match(/(\d+)((?:\.?)\d*)?/)
# ["50.", "50", "."]

m = "50".match(/(\d+)((?:\.?)\d*)?/)
# ["50", "50", ""]
```

But then you'd have to check for `"."` instead of checking for `undefined`. You could start adding more groups and alternations to take care of the single `"."` problem but I don't see how that would be any better than:

```
first  = m[1];
second = m[2] || '';
```

Comment: it still returns undefined for the second value.  Can it return an empty string like in `'abc',split('c');//['ab','']`

Comment: I don't think there's much point to trying to do it all with one single regex but I've added some possibilities in an update.

Answer (score 0):

The | is the alternative operator. `/\.|$/` matches either a '.' or $, which stands for the end of the string. The reason putting the $ in the regex doesn't result in an empty string in the array is because split never puts the thing you split the string on into the array. You'll notice that the decimal point is "missing" as well.

Answer (score 0):

I laugh sometimes at the lengths that people will go solve a problem with a regex when a few lines of regular non-regex code are sometimes much more readable, easier to control the exact result and probably an order of magnitude faster.

Here's a non regex way to produce a two element array, where the first element of the array has the left part of the number and the second element of the array has the decimal part of the number and is always preceded with a period.

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vTPrv/.

Code:

```
var testStrings = [
    "50",
    "50.",
    "50.4",
    "0.4",
    ".4",
    "0",
    "50.4444"
];

function getDecimalPieces(str) {
    if (str[0] == ".") {
        str = "0" + str;   // make sure we always have first part
    }
    var pieces = str.split(".");
    if (pieces.length == 1) {
        pieces.push("0");   // add decimal part
    }
    if (pieces[1] == "") {
        pieces[1] = "0";
    }
    if (pieces.length > 2) {
        pieces.slice(2);    // remove any extra pieces
    }
    pieces[1] = "." + pieces[1];   // add period back onto decimal piece
    return(pieces);
}

for (var i = 0; i < testStrings.length; i++) {
    var result = getDecimalPieces(testStrings[i]);
    $("#result").append("[" + result[0] + ", " + result[1] + "]<br />");
}
```

Results:

```
[50, .0]
[50, .0]
[50, .4]
[0, .4]
[0, .4]
[0, .0]
[50, .4444]
```

Comment: I am well aware that I could have done it without regex, but I was seeing if it was possible with.  Also the regex is a whole lot shorter then your method, though yours could be shortened some too.

Comment: Shorter is better when there is useless code that can be removed, but I don't subscribe to shorter is better when it's less readable or more fragile or harder to know how it works two years later when someone else has to modify it.  In any case, I'm not arguing one way or the other in this case, just wanted to show a different way.

Comment: Understood, In my case it was the challenge of doing something in the shortest amount of code.  I'm trying to write a function in 140 characters or less.